# Android: save vcard text in contacts

Tags: android, contacts, qr-code, vcf-vcard

i've got a qrcode app that scan also vcard: the result (i save it as a string) is:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:name
N:surname
TE:039390399
and everything else
```

my question is:
how can i save this string in the phone contacts?

Comment: Are you referring to the "and everything else" part? or just asking how you go about adding a new contact, based on this information? "This string" is ambiguous.

Comment: @Zak have you got solution about it..

Answer (score 0):

The [vCard specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) says that you should use `NOTE` which specifies supplemental information or a comment that is associated with the vCard

So, your example should be

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN:name
N:surname
TE:039390399
NOTE:and everything else
```

Answer (score -1):

for this you should make vcard io service you can check below link

http://code.google.com/p/vcardio/

Comment: That's an APK, @Zak asked for some Java code to save a vCard string into Contacts